# How to avoid repeating namespace in aspx page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, namespaces

Is that possible to write namespace into some other file commonly.which should be automatically includes my page.

namespace like:using System;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On web.config add the *namespaces* section as follows:

```
<system.web>
        <pages>
              <namespaces>
                    <add namespace ="...your namespace..." />
                    ...
              </namespaces>
              ...
        </pages>
        ...
</system.web>
```